# Power series summation

Tags: real-analysis, summation, power-series

Trying to find the sum of the following infinite series:

$$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{(2n-1)3^{n-1}}$$

Any ideas on how to find this sum?

Comment: Why a vote to close? This question looks pretty legit.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: All: the same question was asked by two students within a few hours. I merged them and deleted the comments under the later version. This explains some of the strange things visible on this page. As usual, the lazy askers and answerers may deserve what they get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that for suitable $t$,
$$\frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-t^6+\cdots.$$
Integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$. We get
$$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots.$$
Divide by $x$. We get
$$\frac{\arctan x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{5}-\frac{x^6}{7}+\cdots.$$
Finally, let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Nice solution, +1! I wonder if there is a way to do it only assuming the value of $\zeta(2)$ ...

$$S=1-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{27}\cdot \frac{1}{7}+\cdots$$

$$\frac{1}{3}S=0+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{27} \cdot \frac{1}{5}-\cdots$$

If you add these two maybe something works out? ... or maybe it is just best to do it your way :D

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee:  It would be nice to link it to $\zeta(2)$ but I can't think of a way. They seem quite different in character, $\zeta(2)$ has that "extra" $\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$$
Then
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}$$
$$x\, f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$
$$(x\, f(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-x^2)^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-x^2)^n}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$x\, f(x)=\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}={\tan}^{-1}x$$
$$f(x)=\frac{{\tan}^{-1}x}{x}$$
Your series is equal to
$$f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Comment: And of course, the arctangent of $1/\sqrt{3}$ is $\pi/6$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\text{arctanh }x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$

Comment: Thanks, I understand the hint. I think arctan is a better series than arctanh to use.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{x^{n-1}}{2n-1} = \frac{y^{2n-2}}{2n-1} \quad \text{where }y=\sqrt x
$$
and
$$
\frac d {dy}\, \frac{y^{2n-1}}{2n-1} = y^{2(n-1)} = x^{n-1}.
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.
$$
The derivative of this with respect to $y$ is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^{2n-1} = \frac y {1-y^2} = \frac A {1-y} + \frac B {1+y}, 
$$
so find the antiderivative of that with respect to $y$ (you'll need to find $A$ and $B$) and after that, figure out what it has to do with the function of $x=y^2$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't you have:
$$
\frac{x^{n-1}}{2n-1} = \frac{y^{2n-2}}{2n-1} \quad \text{where }y=\sqrt x
$$

Comment: @JHobern : Yes.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the geometric sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac {x^2}3\right)^n$

This series is also $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(-\frac{x^2}3\right)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(-\frac13\right)^{k-1} x^{2k-2}$ and an integration from 0 to x give

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(-\frac13\right)^{k-1} \frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$. So you can calculate the sum of the series from the geometric sum.